Is the new android studio update causing problem?
I added video_player to my flutter project pubspec.yaml and after that, this happened:
Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':video_player_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

Also, I updated my Android Studio to Android Studio Lady Bug.
my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.meditation_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.//"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

and I'm using ggradle-8.3-all.zip .
any solution?
I totally do nothing.

are you using video_player package ?

yes  I'm using video_player package  and after add it to my pubspec.yaml file this happend .

This is due to Android studio Lady bug 2024.2 using JDK 21 instead of JDK 17 by default , there are two solutions:

Downgrade to Android studio 2024.1 and wait until Flutter team throw an update to Flutter so that it can upgrade all the android dependencies to work with JDK 21

Do it manually by following this link How to fix Android Compilation issues



I use second solution and fix my error .

There have been changes in the new versions of this file. Now your file has the following changes with my file:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

Change these and then:
flutter clean
flutter pub get

With these changes my project works properly.

I change following codes in my build.gradle file but error not fixed and again that same exact error .

After changing the codes, type the following command: flutter clean and flutter pub get ,
After this you need to build again.With these changes my project works properly.

I did what you said but nothing changed .

In my opinion, create a new project and transfer the previous project files to the new project.

I did that but after adding video player plugin i see this error again .

Do you want to give me access to your source?

That is wrong, targeting 17 is the new approach, and now Flutter has to update all dependenies to work with JDK 21 not the other way around, I believe you are using an old version of android studio or you have no package that needs jdk 17 or higher to work
